# why is jq not working inside bash variable

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I have the following code

```
#/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

requestResponse=$(ssh jump.gcp.xxxxxxx """source dev2 spi-dev
kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] |select(.metadata.name[0:3]=="fea")'  | jq .status.podIP
2>&1""")
echo $requestResponse
```

In the above code `source dev2 spi-dev` means we have moved to spi-dev namespace inside dev2 cluster. `kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] |select(.metadata.name[0:3]=="fea")'  | jq .status.podIP 2>&1""")`  means to print ip address of pod starting with fea. If I do manually kubectl command works. I have also tried escaping fea like `\"fea\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These triple quotes `"""` are not working as you expect.
Try to change it like this:

```
ssh jump.gcp.xxxxxxx << EOF
source dev2 spi-dev
kubectl get pods -o json             | \
jq '.items[]                         | \
select(.metadata.name[0:3]=="fea")'  | \
jq .status.podIP 2>&1
EOF
```